# how would i go about timing the visibility of an image with javascript, e.g. using myTimer

Tags: javascript

I can easily change the visibility of an image by setting controls for it, but how would I time the image to appear and disappear when I want? Could the visibility be a variable under a function such as myTimer?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer with an appropriate level of certainty. It requires more information and more consideration. Answering takes time, and saving the people you want to answer your question time by composing a well rounded question will end up getting more votes and higher quality answers.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some sample code of how you currently change the visibility, and some code attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: A good example to look at would be how jQuery implements its fade function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating two functions calling each other using `setTimeOut`:

```
function display(){
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("mydiv").style.visibility = "visible";hide() }, 1000);
}
function hide(){
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("mydiv").style.visibility = "hidden";display() }, 1000);
}

hide();
```